# MySQL table left join not matching (MySQL, Python)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

**SOLVED see comments and solution**

I have 2 scrapers which store there scraped data in 2 SQL tables: **cpu** and **cpubench**.

**cpu contains**: name, price, id(this is not constant across scrapers), mark

**cpubench contains**: name, mark, cpurank

Here is a snippet from these tables:

**cpu**

`name               price      id      mark
AMD Ryzen 5 2600    $259.00 jLF48d  0
Intel Core i7-8700K $573.74 sxDzK8  0
AMD Ryzen 7 2700X   $449.69 bddxFT  0
Intel Core i5-8600K $396.39 Mr2rxr  0
AMD Ryzen 3 2200G   $145.00 RkJtt6  0
Intel Core i9-9900K $829.61 jHZFf7  0
AMD Ryzen 5 2600X   $300.00 6mm323  0
Intel Core i5-9600K $419.00 28qhP6  0
Intel Core i7-9700K $659.00 WtyV3C  0
AMD Ryzen 5 1600    $232.61 mV98TW  0`

**cpubench**

`name                   mark    cpurank
AMD Ryzen 5 2600        13527   160
Intel Core i7-8700K     15962   98
AMD Ryzen 7 2700X       16971   75
Intel Core i5-8600K     12786   175
AMD Ryzen 3 2200G       7325    503
Intel Core i9-9900K     20150   37
AMD Ryzen 5 2600X       14342   135
Intel Core i5-9600K     13498   162
Intel Core i7-9700K     17379   69
AMD Ryzen 5 1600        12264   187`

Note:

All columns in both tables are **VARCHAR(255)**.

Tables are not in this exact order with names lining up perfectly.

I am using the following python code:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = ("SELECT cpu.id, cpu.name, cpu.price, cpubench.mark FROM cpu LEFT JOIN 
cpubench ON cpu.name = cpubench.name")

mycursor.execute(sql)
```

Which runs without error.

However all the mark values in cpu are null.

How can i troubleshoot/solve this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

I have created a working SQL fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sngju1uUBNMF56eVVTYu6H/3

I have tried the code from the fiddle in python with it running but all cpu.mark values being null.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting null values for "cpubench.mark" ?

Comment: You can give a try to `UPPER(TRIM(cpu.name)) = UPPER(TRIM(cpubench.name))`, Might the actual data has some blank spaces

Comment: @Vivek cpubench.mark contains values however after running my code cpu.mark has only values of null

Comment: @Vivek i have compared the name values from cpu.name and cpubench.name using MySQL workbench, but i will give upper trim a go, where would that go?

Comment: Instead of `sql = ("SELECT cpu.id, cpu.name, cpu.price, cpubench.mark FROM cpu LEFT JOIN 
cpubench ON cpu.name = cpubench.name")`,  Use `sql = ("SELECT cpu.id, cpu.name, cpu.price, cpubench.mark FROM cpu LEFT JOIN 
cpubench ON UPPER(TRIM(cpu.name)) = UPPER(TRIM(cpubench.name))")`

Comment: @Vivek i've changed the code however cpu.mark is still all null. Should i be seeing anything in the shell? Thanks

Comment: Some confusion is there, What you want to Do? 1. `Select the data from both tables and perform some action`? 2. `Do you want to update the mark in cpu table from cpubench`?

Comment: I have 2 tables: cpu and cpubench. They both contain names, cpubench contains a mark for each row. I want to add the mark from cpubench to the corresponding row in cpu if the names match. I think that would be 2. Hopefully that makes sense :)

Comment: Got it, then you don't need of `SELECT` statement you have to update the `cpu` table hence you can use `update cpu join cpubench on UPPER(TRIM(cpu.name)) = UPPER(TRIM(cpubench.name)) set cpu.mark = cpubench.mark` it will solve your issue

Comment: I've just tried that code an it ran fine but it still doesn't seem to update any mark values in cpu as they are all still null. Is there anyway to add some print statements to troubleshoot etc? Thanks

Comment: Here is my table and column layout as shown in workbench. https://imgur.com/a/VNGlVYQ

Comment: If there is any thing else that can help troubleshoot please let me know.

Comment: also here is all the code i used: mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = ("update cpu join cpubench on UPPER(TRIM(cpu.name)) = UPPER(TRIM(cpubench.name)) set cpu.mark = cpubench.mark")


mycursor.execute(sql)

Comment: In SQLFiddle.com design a schema and insert the data than share the link will see.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sngju1uUBNMF56eVVTYu6H/2 hopefully thats what you are looking for, let me know if i need to change anything

Comment: Updated the sqlfiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sngju1uUBNMF56eVVTYu6H/2 check it now

Comment: when i run that i get Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cpu table hence you can use update cpu join cpubench on UPPER(TRIM(cpu.name)) = ' at line 1

Comment: I think i might have done the sqlfiddle wrong as this is the code i use to make table. CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cpu (name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE, price VARCHAR(255), id VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE). I don't think it should have ('""')

Comment: Actually, you don't need to use any quotes for creating table statement until you want to make columns case sensitive. Just remove all the quotes (Single/Double) while creating the tables and re check.

Comment: Thanks ok will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS per comments, am binding the final solution here:

```
update cpu 
join cpubench on UPPER(TRIM(cpu.`"name"`)) = UPPER(TRIM(cpubench.`"name"`)) 
set cpu.`"mark"` = cpubench.`"mark"`;

SELECT * FROM cpu;
```

Comment: at the moment i have: sql = ("update cpu join cpubench on UPPER(TRIM(cpu.name)) = UPPER(TRIM(cpubench.name)) set cpu.mark = cpubench.mark") see above comments but that doesn't seem to be working. Thanks

Comment: `mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = ('update cpu 
join cpubench on UPPER(TRIM(cpu.`"name"`)) = UPPER(TRIM(cpubench.`"name"`)) 
set cpu.`"mark"` = cpubench.`"mark"`')

mycursor.execute(sql)

sql = ('select * from cpu')

mycursor.execute(sql)`

Comment: With the line of code: sql = ('update cpu join cpubench on UPPER(TRIM(cpu."name")) = UPPER(TRIM(cpubench."name")) set cpu."mark" = cpubench."mark"') I get error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"name")) = UPPER(TRIM(cpubench."name")) set cpu."mark" = cpubench."mark"' at line 1

Comment: ok so now i have: sql = ("update cpu join cpubench on UPPER(TRIM(cpu.name)) = UPPER(TRIM(cpubench.name)) set cpu.mark = cpubench.mark"). However it still doesn't seem to work?

Comment: ok so I've got the fiddle working: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sngju1uUBNMF56eVVTYu6H/4 and i used that code in python but it doesn't work: mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = ("update cpu join cpubench on UPPER(TRIM(cpu.name)) = UPPER(TRIM(cpubench.name)) set cpu.mark = cpubench.mark")

mycursor.execute(sql)

Comment: So I'm really stumped now.

Comment: if this is any help I added: myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
  print(x). Which gives give: raise errors.InterfaceError("No result set to fetch from.")
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.

Comment: Also do you have any idea for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788790/how-to-divide-2-varchar255-values-mysql-python