# How to divide 2 VARCHAR(255) values and insert into row (MySQL, Python)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

**Table data:**

I have a table cpu with the columns name, price, id, mark, value

**Data format:**

The price value is $xxx.xx and the mark value is xxxxxx both stored as VARCHAR(255)'s.

**Question:**

How can i divide price into mark and then store that variable in value for each row using MySQL python?

I had the following idea regarding code: for each row get price and mark check they both have a value, convert price to a float by removing the "$" and setting it to a float. I could then set mark to a float so i can divide price into mark and save this value as a VARCHAR(255) into the value column before moving onto the next row until i have been through all rows.

**Python table creation code:**

```
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cpu (name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE, price VARCHAR(255), id VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE, mark VARCHAR(255), value VARCHAR(255))")
```

**SQL fiddle:**

[SQL fiddle of table structure](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sngju1uUBNMF56eVVTYu6H/5)

**Example:**

price: $250, mark: 13500

I want to divide mark by price to calculate the value (marks per dollar)

I want this value stored as number e.g.

value: 54

I want this to happen for each row untill all rows are complete, if there is no value for either field I want to skip the row.

**Update:**

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

number_of_rows = mycursor.execute("select * from cpu")

result = mycursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
  print(row)
```

The above code loop's through all rows but im not sure how to only print price and mark, im also not sure how to insert a value for value in each row?

**Other**

If you need any more details please let me know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Post text results of SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;   please.

Comment: And post your Example table with data so we have your data to work with, please.

Comment: Here you go: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sngju1uUBNMF56eVVTYu6H/5 Thanks

Comment: I was thinking that i had to convert price to a float in python by removing the "$" then converting to a float along with mark so i can divide them to create value. However I'm not sure of the code to do so.

Thanks

Comment: I have also updated the post with the information along with other things I believe might be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Having all columns varchar type despite some of them clearly containing numeric values is just wrong on so many levels. This has huge performance penalty and in the long run is not sustainable. If you fix your database table design to begin with, your question ceases to exist.

Hint: currency (USD) and decimal price should be 2 different columns.

Comment: Thank you, I understand and will change column type however the issue I am facing is the python MySQL code to loop through each row in the table check both price and mark have a value then divide them and insert the answer into the value column.

Comment: Hopefully that clarifies it. Thanks

Comment: Ok so i've managed to figure out how to loop through the rows with: mycursor = mydb.cursor()
 
number_of_rows = mycursor.execute("select * from cpu")
 
result = mycursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
  print(row)

Comment: I was thinking i should add a id column to help using: "INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT num, price, mark FROM cpu")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
  print(x)
  y = str(x)
  num, price, mark = y.split(',')
  num = num.replace("(", "")
  price = price.replace("'", "")
  price = price.replace(" ", "")
  price = price.replace("$", "")
  mark = mark.replace(")", "")
  mark = mark.replace("'", "")
  mark = mark.replace(" ", "")
  price = float(price)
  if mark != "None":
    mark = float(mark)
    value = mark/price
  else:
    value = 0
  value = round(value, 2)
  value = str(value)
  num = str(num)
  print(num)
  print(price)
  print(mark)
  print(value)
  sql = "UPDATE cpu SET value = " + value + " WHERE num = " + num +";"
  print(sql)
  mycursor.execute(sql)

  mydb.commit()

mydb.commit()
```

This is the code i made which solved my problem, I'm almost sure it could be improved so feel feel free to add another answer or comment and i'll change it.